# Razor Return File returning multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, razor

I have a return File that is offering to download a file but is also downloading the file to another location, I would just like it to offer to download to the user one file, i.e. it reads the initial data from memory, so the first argument in the return File is a MemoryStream of some sort, but I can't figure out how to do it

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FilePathResult FileToFasta(F2FModel model)
    {

        string FullText = new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        TextLayer layer = new TextLayer(FullText);
        string outputFile = layer.WriteToFasta();

        String mydatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
        string FileName = String.Format("TextFile{0}.txt", mydatetime);
        string FilePath = @"F:\test\" + FileName;
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(FilePath);
        if (!info.Exists)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
            {
                writer.Write(outputFile);
            }
        }
        return File(FilePath, "text/plain", FileName);

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemoryStream` can be used with [`FileStreamResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), for example like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public FilePathResult FileToFasta(F2FModel model)
{
    string FullText = new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    TextLayer layer = new TextLayer(FullText);
    string outputFile = layer.WriteToFasta();

    string mydatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
    string FileName = String.Format("TextFile{0}.txt", mydatetime);

    //Use different encoding if needed
    byte[] outputArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(outputFile);
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(outputArray); 

    //FileStreamResult will close the stream for you so don't worry
    return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "text/plain") { FileDownloadName = FileName };
}
```